# Как сделать нумерацию страниц в php?

Tags: php, mysql, phpstorm

Как сделать последовательную нумерацию страниц как в примере ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
require_once('../setting/config/MySQL.php');

$total = $c->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `news` WHERE `id`');
$total->execute();
$total_page = $total->fetchColumn();

$get = $_GET;
$pages = $get['page'];
for ($pages = 1; $pages  <= 10; $pages++){

        echo '<a href=/?pages=' . $pages . '>' . $pages . '</a>';

}
```

Я понимаю что мой код выводит просто 10 ссылок, подскажите как правильно?

Comment: Вот тут хороший пример создания пагинации http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=examples&page=062

Comment: правильно будет взять и продумать алгоритм сначала, а не пытаться писать код. Когда детали алгоритма будут ясны, то написать код не сложно. Так что придумайте различные в т.ч. крайние варианты состояний пейджбара и составьте алгоритм

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался .